# Installing toolboxes in Octave

Tags: installation, octave, toolbox

In order to realise some course's activity in Octave, found in the following site

https://nbviewer.org/github/gpeyre/numerical-tours/blob/master/matlab/audio_1_processing.ipynb#

I needed to install some toolboxes found in

http://www.numerical-tours.com/installation_matlab/

Two of them seems to be easily installed via `pkg install -forge ...` (I have Linux Mint 19), these toolboxes are 'general' and 'signal', but 'graph' and 'wavelet_meshes' seems not to be directly available for Octave.

1 - So, if I downloaded them manually.. how should I install these packages? I do not even find Octave directory using 'whereis' in order to localise a proper folder to throw toolboxes files (its path shown located in /app/share/octave when open).

2 - Another thing.. should I spect to use toolboxes automatically after toolbox is installed? or may I indicate its selection in some specific way? ..I ask this because after running the following script chunk

```
n = 1024*16;
options.n = n;
[x,fs] = load_sound('bird', n);
```

command window throws the following message

```
error: 'load_sound' undefined near line 3, column 4
```

so I understand Octave does not recognises 'load_sound' function, which is from 'signal' toolbox (that is already installed).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Packages can be installed from compressed package files if they were prepared for that method. `pkg install <filename>`  if not, and you just have a folder of function files, you may be able to put them somewhere local and use `addpath`.  Then octave would be able to find them no matter what folder you were actually working in.

Comment: It would help if your question actually pointed to the packages for us to see.  You should Aldo try `help pkg` where you would we that you must load a pkg before its files are available for use.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but basically you're confusing a few things. Octave has formal packages which are of a particular format, and it so happens that there's an official "general" and "signal" package. But these are just names. They have nothing to do with what you're doing here. Here you are given zipfiles. Just unzip them, and the functions are plain .m files that you can run from within their folder. If you want to use them more generally, you can use the `addpath` function to add those folders to the 'path'.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I found that packages not installed by commands weren't simply included in path. I just added corresponding folders and I _may_ say it worked. Nevertheless, it seems packages downloaded from this link lack of certain scripts, such as 'wavread' in 'signal'. So, it remains to make an effort in looking out for missing ones..